# “X shares a lot of system state across process boundaries”

Tags: unity, xorg, wayland, mir

## The background

I was to get informed about the state of Wayland adoption by Ubuntu, when I learned it's not any more an option and there is something named Mir in the place instead. So I wanted to learn more about the reasons.

## The question

The page [MirSpec](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mir/Spec?action=show&redirect=MirSpec) at wiki.ubuntu.com says:

> With respect to shell development (Unity), three major shortcomings of the X stack prevent us from delivering the user experience (f’n’f) we have in mind:
>
> - **X shares a lot of system state across process boundaries.** […]
> - …

I could not understand the sentence I underlined in bold, which seems to be an important point understanding both X and Mir.

Is there any kind of practical/concrete pictures to explain what this statement means?